# Finding two minimum using INT_MAX in linked list is giving segmentation error

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to find the minimum two numbers in a linked list since yesterday but still not able to do yet so decided to ask at stackoverflow.

My logic to do so is :

(1) First set min1->freq and min2->freq to `INT_MAX` they are both of node type pointer.

(2) Then i set the second smallest then the first smallest like this :

```
while (temp != NULL) 
{
    printf("\ncheck2\n");       
    if ((temp) -> freq < min2 -> freq)
    {
        printf("check3\n");
        min1 = min2;
        min2 = temp;
    } 
    else if ((temp) -> freq < min1 -> freq && (temp) -> freq != min2 -> freq)
    {
        printf("check4\n");
        min1 = temp;
    }
    temp = temp -> next;
}
* lmin1 = min1; 
* lmin2 = min2;
```

Error:

```
The error i am getting is this :
enter the size of node
4
start entering the number of elements until your size
0
-1
-5
8
Printing linked list
0-> -1-> -5-> 8-> 
check0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**I debugged manually by printf statments i found that the initialization of `min2 -> freq = INT_MAX;` is creating problem (please see in my full code below) because it is not able to print "check1" just prints "check0"**

If you want to have look to my full code then please find below :

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <limits.h>

struct node 
{
    int freq;
    struct node * next;
};
typedef struct node node;
node * tree;

//Problem creating area is below (code for finding minimum two elements)
void find_two_min(node * * List, node * * lmin1, node * * lmin2) 
{

    node * temp = * List;
    node * min1;
    min1 -> freq = INT_MAX;
    node * min2;
    printf("\ncheck0\n");
    min2 -> freq = INT_MAX;  //This initialisation of INT_MAX to min2->freq creates problem because printf() statment above it works well but don't work below it.
    printf("check1\n");
    while (temp != NULL) 
    {
        printf("\ncheck2\n");

        if ((temp) -> freq < min2 -> freq)
        {
            printf("check3\n");
            min1 = min2;
            min2 = temp;
        } 
        else if ((temp) -> freq < min1 -> freq && (temp) -> freq != min2 -> freq)
        {
            printf("check4\n");
            min1 = temp;
        }
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
    * lmin1 = min1; 
    * lmin2 = min2;
    printf("check5\n"); 
}
//Problem creating area is above//
void main() 
{
    int size, data;
    node * min1;
    node * min2;
    int count = 0; //this count flag is to check is it's first node or not inside the do-while loop.
    tree = NULL;
    printf("enter the size of node\n");
    scanf("%d", & size);
    printf("start entering the number of elements until your size\n");
    node * prev;
    do {
        scanf("%d", & data);
        if (count == 0)
        {
            node * temp;
            temp = (node * ) malloc(sizeof(node));
            temp -> freq = data;
            temp -> next = NULL;
            prev = temp;
            tree = prev;
        }
        else 
        {
            node * temp;
            temp = (node * ) malloc(sizeof(node));
            temp -> freq = data;
            temp -> next = NULL;
            prev -> next = temp;
            prev = prev -> next;
        }
        size--;
        ++count;
    }
    while (size > 0);

    printf("Printing linked list\n");
    node * temp1;
    temp1 = tree;
    while (temp1 != NULL) 
    {
        printf("%d-> ", temp1 -> freq);
        temp1 = temp1 -> next;
    }
    node * temp5 = tree;
    find_two_min( & temp5, & min1, & min2);
    printf("\n The two minimum numbers are  min1 :%d   and min2 : %d\n", min1 -> freq, min2 -> freq);

}
```

Could anyone please help me in correcting in **c/c++** ? Thanks

Comment: Use the right tools, `gdb` will help you with this.

Comment: Simply compiling with warnings turned on should throw a very clear "use of uninitialized variable" warning that points directly to the issue.

Comment: @AndrewMedico sorry , couldn't understand what you said ?It has been solved i needed to create node using malloc/new. But i have one more doubt that I don't know why we assigned INT_MAX to min1 and min2 ? I tried to google it but couldn't understand it. what does it do, Do you know any other alternative to achieve the same target ?

Comment: Your compiler should be printing a warning like `test.c(24) : warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'min2' used` which points out the fact that you haven't initialized `min2` and are consequently dereferencing some garbage value and writing to that location.

Comment: Ok thanks and second question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`min2` is a pointer to which no memory has been allocated. Use `new` to allocate and `delete` to deallocate memory.

The way you write it:

```
node * min2;
printf("\ncheck0\n");
min2 -> freq = INT_MAX;  //This initialisation of INT_MAX to min2->freq creates problem because printf() statment above it works well but don't work below it.
printf("check1\n");
```

Explanation:

```
let `min2` be a pointer to a memory area holding a node. The pointer is random.
initialize the member `freq` of the structure pointed to by min2.
```

The result is a attempt to write to random memory, which *might* result in a segfault.

Comment: thanks,let me try it and any comment about my logic to do so ?

Comment: I didn't check your logic.

Comment: Thanks it worked but still a don't know whu we assigned INT_MAX to min1 and min2 ? I tried to google it but couldn't understand it. what does it do, Do you know any other alternative to achieve the same target ?

Comment: The algorithm works by step-by-step minimizing the number. If it finds a number smaller than the smallest number up to then, the new smallest number is set to it. INT_MAX is the largest possible number, to which every (the first for example) number is smaller. If one would take 10 and the smallest found number would be 11, the result would be 10, because 11 is not smaller than 10.